# Python Multiple Datetimes To One

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, datetime-format

I have two types of datetime format in a Dataframe.

```
Date
2019-01-06  00:00:00 (%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')
07/17/2018 ('%m/%d/%Y')
```

I want to convert into one specific datetime format. Below is the script that I am using

```
d1 = pd.to_datetime(df1['DATE'], format='%m/%d/%Y',errors='coerce')
d2 = pd.to_datetime(df1['DATE'], format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S',errors='coerce')
df1['Date'] = d2.fillna(d1)
```

While doing this, the code is clubbing some of the other datetime into another. For ex: 7th January 2018 is coming as July 1st 2018. This problem is associated with  this format (%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S') after running the above script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are mixed format also in format `2019-01-06  00:00:00` - it means it should be January or June, only ways is prioritize one format - e.g. here first months and add first format `d2` and then `d3` in chained `fillna`:

```
d1 = pd.to_datetime(df1['DATE'], format='%m/%d/%Y',errors='coerce')
d2 = pd.to_datetime(df1['DATE'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',errors='coerce')
d3 = pd.to_datetime(df1['DATE'], format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S',errors='coerce')

df1['Date'] = d2.fillna(d1).fillna(d3)
```

If need prioritize first days:

```
df1['Date'] = d3.fillna(d1).fillna(d2)
```

In sample data is possible check difference:

```
print (df1)
                  DATE
0  2019-01-06 00:00:00
1  2019-01-15 00:00:00
2  2019-20-10 00:00:00
3           07/17/2018

d1 = pd.to_datetime(df1['DATE'], format='%m/%d/%Y',errors='coerce')
d2 = pd.to_datetime(df1['DATE'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',errors='coerce')
d3 = pd.to_datetime(df1['DATE'], format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S',errors='coerce')

df1['Date1'] = d2.fillna(d1).fillna(d3)
df1['Date2'] = d3.fillna(d1).fillna(d2)
print (df1)
                  DATE      Date1      Date2
0  2019-01-06 00:00:00 2019-01-06 2019-06-01 <- difference
1  2019-01-15 00:00:00 2019-01-15 2019-01-15
2  2019-20-10 00:00:00 2019-10-20 2019-10-20
3           07/17/2018 2018-07-17 2018-07-17
```

Comment: @AB14 - Is possible add some problematic datetimes in question and add expected ouput?

Comment: While following the same below is the output I am getting
1 ) df1['Date'] = d2.fillna(d1).fillna(d3) - reshufling of months again happening
 2) df1['Date'] = d3.fillna(d1).fillna(d2) -  output is  2018-07-17 (Y-m-d) &  2019-01-06 (Y-d-m)

Comment: @AB14 - Added to answer with some data for see difference.